# Notation on definition of spherical symmetry of spacetime

Tags: matrices, symmetric-groups

In reading something about relativity and in particular looking at first to the definition of spacetime as "spherically symmetric" I have encountered the following notation referred to an element of the orthogonal special group of $\mathbb{R}^3$ ($SO(3)$):
$$R\in SO(3)\iff \begin{cases} {}^{t}_{}R I R=I\\ det(R)=1 \end{cases} $$
What is the meaning of the superscript $t$? Which operation of matrices correspond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That superscript $^t$ is (bad, in my opinion) notation for the matrix transpose. That is, if $$R = \pmatrix{a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i}$$, then $^tR$ (urgh, the kerning) is simply the matrix $$\pmatrix{a & d & g\\b & e & h\\c & f & i}.$$

Comment: You mean keming ;)

Comment: I agree it is a quite bad notation. Many thanks!